# Insert a duplicate record in SQL Server with identity column ON

Tags: sql-server

Here is my requirement: I want to insert some duplicate records into my SQL Server table. A column called `QID` is the PK - identity column auto increments by 1.

I tried the following ways:

```
insert into qtable 
    select top 1 * 
    from qtable
```

which caused an error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'qtable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Then I tried without the identity column including all columns in the table.

```
INSERT INTO qtable  
    SELECT TOP 1   
        col1, col2, col3, col4...  
    FROM
        qtable
```

which gave me values inserted but col1 value was shifted to col2 and col2 to col3 and so on and col1 had the identity value.

How can I insert a duplicate record but identity column must be auto incremented?

Comment: You cannot. It's the primary key. That means each row is *uniquely* identifiable by the values in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the columns for your insert statement.

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO qtable (col1,col2,col3) 
select top 1 col1
   , col2
   , col3 
from qtable
```